# Determine if current page is using SSL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I'm trying to detect if the current page is being delivered via SSL in order to decide whether or not to include certain unsecure external resources. My current method involves checking if `request.url` starts with 'https'. Is this the simplest way of accomplishing this? Is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In a controller or view:

```
request.ssl?
```

Comment: Also works in views (eg, to show an SSL badge for https requests)

Comment: Actually I think checking that the protocol has 'https' is going to be a lot safer than this. The header could be manipulated in transit. All you're checking with request.ssl? is @env['HTTPS'] == 'on' || @env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'

Whereas the fullpath, being the request and having the protocol, couldn't be spoofed.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Request/ssl%3F

Comment: I was wrong, the entire header is encrypted and cannot be tampered with in transit.